# MDX Range with non existing members

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a `MDX` query where the string is parsed from a front-end application with forms. End users can restrict a query based on a free text field where they can input a range from invoice number and to invoice number. The query gets build based on this 2 parameters:

```
SELECT
  {[Measures].[Amount]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
  (
    (
      [Invoices].[Invoice Number].[Invoice Number].[100000000]:[Invoices].[Invoice Number].[Invoice Number].[222222222])
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]
```

However the range operator fails if an end user types in a non existing member. I think that I need to convert these fields somehow to a decimal number and than do the check with > and <.

I already have some ideas. However I am not able to get it to work. Here I try to just filter on numbers > 0 (If this works I can fill the the parameter for > and add one for <.

```
SELECT 
   {[Measures].[Amount]} ON COLUMNS,
   (
     FILTER(
       [Invoices].[Invoice Number].[Invoice Number].members
     , Cdec([Invoices].[Invoice Number].Currentmember.Properties("Key")) > 0
     )
   ) ON ROWS   
FROM [MyCybe]
```

However after 5 minutes I still have no response.. so cancelled the query.

Comment: Where is ON ROWS? Or you just didn't write it here? I've tested the same query (with `on rows`) on my DB and it works. Have you tried to trace by Profiler to capture all server events?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I have the ON ROWS in my syntax. Just missed the syntax with making the example simpler to come to the core of the problem.

Comment: How many members has `[Invoices]` dimension? Did you use Profiler to trace?

Comment: 6M. did not use the profiler yet. do not have experience in using it. I will try.

Comment: Here is the explanation of events for SSAS: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1745747

Comment: Another questions: what is the cube size? Are there partitions? Slices? Do indexes of `[Invoice Number]` attribute set to FullOptiomized or NotOptimized?

Comment: @AlexPeshik I was able to solve it! If I changed my FILTER([], condition) to FILTER( NON EMPTY([],[Measure]), condition) it works very fast! Super thank you also for the information. It led me to new insights.

Comment: You're welcome! I believe, by using NON EMPTY, you switched server from cell-by-cell to block mode, that's why it's so fast now.

Answer (score 2):

I've calculated this way (it's for dates, but the idea is the same):

```
with
member [Measures].[RD_Key] as CDec([Report Date].[Report Date ID].Currentmember.Member_Key)

member [Measures].[ResultFilter] as [RD_Key]>20130801 and [RD_Key]<20131013

select {[Measures].[Count],[Measures].[RD_Key]} on 0
,Filter([Report Date].[Report Date ID].members,[Measures].[ResultFilter]) on 1
FROM [DATA]
```

Answer (score 2):

If `FILTER` is slow maybe try using the `HAVING` clause. I'm assuming that no conversion of the `Member_Key` is needed as keys are usually numeric:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[Inv_Key] as 
    [Invoices].[Invoice Number].Currentmember.Member_Key
SELECT
  {
    [Measures].[Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Inv_Key]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,[Invoices].[Invoice Number].[Invoice Number].members
  HAVING  
      [Measures].[Inv_Key] > 100000000
      AND
      [Measures].[Inv_Key] < 222222222
    ON ROWS
FROM [DATA]
```